# file transfer using informatica or contrl -M

Tags: unix, ftp, informatica

I want to transfer a file that is generated through informatica on a unix server to another unix server in a different environment. I have researched on it and came to know that I can either trigger the ftp through informatica or Control-M. I have never done ftp setup before therefore I am trying to understand the difference between the two aproaches and how can I fulfill the requirements regarding these approaches. If I can get any guidance regarding the above it would be greatly appreciated. I apologize if my question is broad because right now I am myself trying to find a way to understand how both approaches actually work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are fine. If you do it through Control M you have to setup a separate job, add dependencies etc.

However if you do it using a command task in Informatica then you do not have to create another job in control m. I would go with the Informatica approach since the file always needs to be sent to the remote server whenever generated by Informatica